# How to use this argument in this async lambda?

Tags: rust

I'm trying the below code but I cannot understand how to fix the error, can you help me?

RUST PLAYGROUND DEMO: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=977a9e7a5bb503e900818b8ff67daf7e

Code:

```rust
use std::{future::Future, pin::Pin, sync::Arc};

#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait PlayerTrait: Send + Sync {
    async fn player_update<'a>(
        &'a self,
        input: PlayerInput,
        lambda: &(dyn Fn(
            PlayerLambdaArgs,
        ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player, String>> + Send + 'a>>
              + Sync),
    ) -> Result<Player, String>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Player {
    pub name: String,
}

impl Player {
    pub fn new(name: &str, team_id: i64) -> Result<Player, String> {
        if team_id > 100 {
            return Err("Sorry, this team is closed".to_string());
        }

        Ok(Player {
            name: name.to_string(),
        })
    }
}

pub struct PlayerInput {
    pub name: String,
}

pub struct PlayerLambdaArgs {
    pub random_team_id: i64,
}

pub struct DBRepo {
    pub db: String,
}

impl DBRepo {
    pub fn new(db: String) -> Self {
        Self { db }
    }
}

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl PlayerTrait for DBRepo {
    async fn player_update<'a>(
        &'a self,
        _input: PlayerInput,
        lambda: &(dyn Fn(
            PlayerLambdaArgs,
        ) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<Player, String>> + Send + 'a>>
              + Sync),
    ) -> Result<Player, String> {
        // get from DB here
        let random_team_id = 123;

        let lambda_args = PlayerLambdaArgs { random_team_id };

        let res = lambda(lambda_args).await?;

        // do something with res here
        Ok(Player { name: res.name })
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db_repo = Arc::new(DBRepo::new(String::from("hello")));

    let input = PlayerInput {
        name: "Bob".to_string(),
    };

    let player = db_repo
        .player_update(input, &|args| {
            Box::pin(async {
                let player = Player::new(&input.name, args.random_team_id)?;

                Ok(player)
            })
        })
        .await;

    dbg!(player);
}
```

Error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `args.random_team_id`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:82:28
   |
82 |               Box::pin(async {
   |  ____________________________^
83 | |                 let player = Player::new(&input.name, args.random_team_id)?;
   | |                                                       ------------------- `args.random_team_id` is borrowed here
84 | |
85 | |                 Ok(player)
86 | |             })
   | |_____________^ may outlive borrowed value `args.random_team_id`
   |
note: async block is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:82:13
   |
82 | /             Box::pin(async {
83 | |                 let player = Player::new(&input.name, args.random_team_id)?;
84 | |
85 | |                 Ok(player)
86 | |             })
   | |______________^
help: to force the async block to take ownership of `args.random_team_id` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
82 |             Box::pin(async move {
   |                            ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, pretty much always, async closures must also be `move`. This also means that any closure they're inside must be `move` as well.

So the first thing to do is add `move`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db_repo = Arc::new(DBRepo::new(String::from("hello")));

    let input = PlayerInput {
        name: "Bob".to_string(),
    };

    let player = db_repo
        .player_update(input, &(move |args| {
            Box::pin(async move {
                let player = Player::new(&input.name, args.random_team_id)?;

                Ok(player)
            })
        }))
        .await;

    dbg!(player);
}
```

We're still getting some errors here around `input.name`. This is because we're trying to move `input` as an argument to `player_update` and as a capture of the closure and the async block.

So let's add a clone for the `PlayerInput` construction:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db_repo = Arc::new(DBRepo::new(String::from("hello")));

    let name = "Bob".to_string();

    let input = PlayerInput {
        name: name.clone(),
    };

    let player = db_repo
        .player_update(input, &(move |args| {
            Box::pin(async move {
                let player = Player::new(&name, args.random_team_id)?;

                Ok(player)
            })
        }))
        .await;

    dbg!(player);
}
```

This leads to one final move error. We can fix this by taking a reference to `name` outside the closure, instead of inside it:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let db_repo = Arc::new(DBRepo::new(String::from("hello")));

    let name = "Bob".to_string();
    let name = &name;

    let input = PlayerInput {
        name: name.clone(),
    };

    let player = db_repo
        .player_update(input, &(move |args| {
            Box::pin(async move {
                let player = Player::new(name, args.random_team_id)?;

                Ok(player)
            })
        }))
        .await;

    dbg!(player);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6efc4b7f289ce4d1d15256ded9b43a4)

Comment: Thank you very much.

I understood the `move` fix (although I don't understand why to put it twice (even in front of the `|args|`, I tried with `Box::pin(async move` only and it works).

The real issue now is with `input`: I cannot change it because it's a struct coming from HTTP endpoints. What do you suggest?

Comment: `clone` out of input instead of cloning when constructing it?

Comment: There is no other way? No other pattern?

Comment: Without a clearer example, it's hard to say. Maybe you could pass `input` to `player_update` by reference instead?

Comment: Yeah. Even with reference the issue is the same. Anyway I'm talking about different patterns at all. Like using channels or something else. What do you think?

Comment: What's the purpose of the closure passed to `player_update`?

Comment: Execute code during db transaction for example...

Comment: Sure, but why have a closure? Why not just inline that code into `player_update`? What does having this flexibility enable?

Comment: I'm using Repository pattern, the function is executed during a DB transaction or during other async task (I don't care about speed here).